# Restful Api's: Am I Not Following the RestFul Api's Definition. One of its constraint is that it should be stateless

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Out of six most important constraints of RESTFUL API'S one is that it should be stateless that we should not save any state or variable at server.

[image]

As you can see i am storing id into a constant variable. So Am i not making real Restful Api's. Please Help me

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a screenshot. You can store fields as constants, as long as you do not use the constant outside of the scope of a single call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'stateless' as it pertains to HTTP, means that, in a nutshell HTTP requests should not be interpreted different depending on what HTTP request came before it. All the information about the request should be contained in the request.

For example, if I open a HTTP request and log in, and then I don't close the TCP connection and do another request, the server should not assume I'm still the same user/person. It can only figure that out based on headers such as `Authorization` or `Cookie`.

Your `const` is not even a global constant. It will be re-created for every request.

But even if it were, this probably doesn't matter. If you do a `PUT` request and results in something stored in a database, this is 'state', but unrelated to the statelessness of HTTP.

Comment: So Bro it means using put request and in that request making a local variable and save data to it is against stateless definition?

Comment: Please can you explain this in easy way . Regards

Comment: Sorry, your question is very hard to understand. Can you try to rephrase?

Comment: Brother My question is. In my apis i can creating variable (tho they are local) and they are storing req data. so they are not against the Stateless definition of restful api's. That what i want to understand. As i know stateless mean you cannot save any state or data on server side.